# Intent extras are null after starting new activity

Tags: android, android-intent

From debugging I can see that the extras are actually in the intent when `startActivity(Intent)` is called. However, once `getIntent()`is called in the new activity, the extras are gone. The intent's extras were fine before I added the `AsyncTask` to handle the long computation.

Below is the code that starts the new activity `RecipeListActivity`

```
public class Fragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
private Entity mEntity;

 private class RecipeOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Recipe>> {
    Context mContext;

    public RecipeOperation(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected  void onPreExecute(){
        // set gui visibilities
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Recipe> doInBackground(Void... param) {
        // long computation
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Recipe> result) {
        //start activity
        Intent i = RecipeListActivity.newIntent(mContext, mEntity.getName(), result);
        mContext.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

}
The `RecipeOperation` task is executed like so

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new RecipeOperation(getActivity()).execute();
        }
    });
```

Below is the activity that I'm starting

```
public class RecipeListActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {
private static final String EXTRA_NAME = "name";
private static final String RECIPES_TAG = "Recipes";

@Override
protected Fragment createFragment(){
    String Name = getIntent().getExtras().getString(EXTRA_NAME);
    ArrayList<Recipe> recipes = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList(RECIPES_TAG);
    return RecipeListFragment.newInstance(Name,recipes);
}

public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContent, String Name, ArrayList<Recipe> recipes){
    Intent intent = new Intent(packageContent,RecipeListActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, Name);
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(RECIPES_TAG,recipes);
    return intent;
}
```

}

Here is the superclass for `RecipeListActivity`

```
public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
protected abstract Fragment createFragment();

@LayoutRes
protected int getLayoutResId(){
    return R.layout.activity_masterdetail;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getLayoutResId());
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = createFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

}

What happened to the intent's extras upon starting the new activity and how can I get the extras to persist?

Comment: `onCreate()` is in the superclass `SingleFragmentActivity`

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in there?

Comment: I added `SingleFragmentActivity` to the question. I have set a breakpoint within that class and the extras are null there as well.

Comment: Maybe your Fragment is recreating that Activity somehow. So, you could try adding in `setRetainInstance(true)` to the Fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the intent's extras were null because there was an error in my `Recipe` class which implements `Parcelable`. Essentially, my `parcel.write`  commands did not match with my `parcel.read` commands.
So if anyone else has this problem check your parcelables. Putting an incorrectly implemented parcelable into an intent will nullify all extras by the time the next activity starts and `getIntent` is called.